Blazor right approach for having everything in wasm but at the same time also have a support for server page rendering for certain pages?
Goal/constraint is to have a SPA, everything in wasm (even router) but at the same time support pages on the server. Greatest flexibility.
Here I accomplished rendering rules by page locations:

If page is on client only, it will render InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode without prerender.
If page is on server only, it will render InteractiveServerRenderMode with prerender.
If page is on server and client, it will render InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode with prerender.

Pages on server that are also on client will be added as a link from the client.
Components on server:
Program.cs:
...
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode();

app.Use404FallbackToClient();

app.Run();

ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:
public static void Use404FallbackToClient(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();

        // Check if the response status code is 404 and the request path doesn't start with "/_framework"
        if (context.Response.StatusCode == StatusCodes.Status404NotFound && !context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/_framework"))
        {
            // Create a new endpoint for the Razor component rendering
            var endpointFeature = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>();
            if (endpointFeature != null)
            {
                endpointFeature.Endpoint = new RouteEndpoint(
                    async httpContext =>
                    {
                        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status200OK;
                        // Render the Blazor component (in this case, App or your custom component)
                        var result = new RazorComponentResult<App>();
                        await result.ExecuteAsync(httpContext);
                    },
                    RoutePatternFactory.Parse("/404"),
                    0,
                    new EndpointMetadataCollection(new[] { new ComponentTypeMetadata(typeof(_404)) }),
                    "404 Endpoint"
                );
            }

            // Render the Razor component directly
            await endpointFeature.Endpoint.RequestDelegate(context);
        }
    });
}

App.razor:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Sindikat.Web.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <RadzenTheme Theme="material" @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    @if (ServerOnlyPage)
    {
        <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    }
    else
    {
        <Sindikat.Web.Client.Components.Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    }
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js?v=@(typeof(Radzen.Colors).Assembly.GetName().Version)"></script>
    <script src="js/sindikatAppBundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
 public partial class App
 {
     private static Assembly serverAssembly;
     private static Assembly clientAssembly;

     static App()
     {
         serverAssembly = typeof(Program).Assembly;
         clientAssembly = typeof(Sindikat.Web.Client.ModuleDefinitions.Module).Assembly;
     }

     [CascadingParameter]
     private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

     private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage { get; set; }
     private bool ServerOnlyPage;

     protected override void OnInitialized()
     {
         var endpointFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>();
         var type = endpointFeature.Endpoint?.Metadata.GetMetadata<ComponentTypeMetadata>()?.Type;

         var hasServerPage = type?.Assembly == serverAssembly;
         var hasClientPage = clientAssembly.GetType($"Sindikat.Web.Client.Components.Pages.{type.Name}") != null;

         ServerOnlyPage = hasServerPage && !hasClientPage;

         var renderMode = type?.GetRenderMode();

         if (renderMode != null)
             RenderModeForPage = renderMode;
         else
             RenderModeForPage = ServerOnlyPage ?
                 new InteractiveServerRenderMode() :
                 new InteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode(hasServerPage);
     }
 }

Routes.razor:
  @using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
    @using Sindikat.Web.Client.Components
    
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <RouteFound RouteData="routeData" />
        </Found>
    </Router>

Components on Client:
Home.razor:
I decided that all pages will only have a component that will have page content.
@page "/"

<Sindikat.Web.Client.Components.Home></Sindikat.Web.Client.Components.Home>

Routes.razor:
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting

<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteFound RouteData="routeData" />
    </Found>
</Router>

404.razor:
@page "/404"


Do you want to execute a specific rendering mode for a specific page?
If so, you can configure a specific endpoint in App.razor, such as
var rm = HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/some point")
By changing the placeholder in the StartsWithSegments method to an appropriate value, you can control the rendering mode used by the rest of the application. For details, please refer to this document :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#area-folder-of-static-ssr-components

Yes and depending where navigation happens, client or server, I can't just navigate to account page on wasm without a reload because router will throw not found and if I reload, that condition based on a path will set the correct render mode. Problem is then when you navigate back to a wasm page and router tries to inject client's services on the server. But all is fixed and working.

@YuningDuan As I stated at the beginning everything is in wasm, even router, because of that you need to render router on server when server pages are used and on wasm when wasm pages are used. Your example works with router on the server all of the time, I presume. My goal is to have SPA app in wasm but also support server pages if ever needed.
